# Where should not jar-like distributions be placed in a standard app folder tree ?

Tags: java, maven, ant

I mean I put all jars in lib folder, together with src, classes, dist, and so on, but if I need to include last Apache CXF or Jetty, which contain bins and the like, where should I place them? Is there any standard?